# using UTF8 in sfml

Tags: c++, utf-8, sfml, cyrillic

I am trying to create something with SFML.

I want to detect what character does the user type and to store it into a variable. Then I want to display it with the sf::Text. It sounds easy but I want to use cyrillic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole paragraph called

> How to avoid problems with non-ASCII characters?

in the tutorials section of SFML on **Texts and fonts** ([Click here to get there](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-text.php#how-to-avoid-problems-with-non-ascii-characters)).

When you follow it, you should be fine.

The [sf::String](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3/classsf_1_1String.php) class accepts both UNICODE and ANSI texts as constructor parameters, so you should be fine whatever input you get.

Comment: text.setString(L"יטאח");          if I use this then only rectangles are printed
@nvoigt

Comment: @K Works You, of course, also need to be using a font that actually contains the characters you want to display. Glyphs are not magically conjoured up, they need to be there in the font.

Comment: but if I type  
text.setString(L"здр"); the comiler shows error : Converting to execution character set Illegal sequence
@Jesper

Comment: @KWorks By the way, which compiler are you using?

Comment: There is my new topic
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507044/sfml-dsplayng-cyrillic-text-from-file
@nvoigt