# Displaying cyrillic text from file

Tags: c++, file, utf-8, sfml, cyrillic

Well, I have got a file with cyrillic characters. I am loading it, getting a string from it and then trying to display it with sf::Text. That's what my code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Learn me");
    sf::Text before;
    wifstream lvl;
    lvl.open("text.txt");
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("CODE2000.ttf");
    before.setFont(font);
    before.setCharacterSize(20);
    before.setColor(sf::Color(150,150,150));
    wstring stri;
    getline(lvl,stri);
    before.setString(stri);
    while(window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            switch(event.type){
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(before);
        window.display();
    }
    lvl.close();
    return 0;
}
```

but this does only display strange characters.

This one is working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"Learn me");
    sf::Text before;
    wifstream lvl;
    lvl.open("text.txt");
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("CODE2000.ttf");
    before.setFont(font);
    before.setCharacterSize(20);
    before.setColor(sf::Color(150,150,150));
    wstring stri;
    getline(lvl,stri);
    sf::String text;
    text=sf::String::fromUtf8(begin(stri),end(stri));
    before.setString(text);
    while(window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            switch(event.type){
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(before);
        window.display();
    }
    lvl.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with SFML, you are just reading your file incorrectly.

C++ uses wide strings (`std::wstring`) to represent UNICODE. This is *not* UTF-8. To read a `std::wstring` from an UTF-8 encoded file, please read [Read Unicode UTF-8 file into wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775437/read-unicode-utf-8-file-into-wstring) and use the second answer.

In case the order changes over time, that would be the one that tells you to use this function:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring readFile(const char* filename)
{
    std::wifstream wif(filename);
    wif.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::empty(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    std::wstringstream wss;
    wss << wif.rdbuf();
    return wss.str();
}
```

Once you have obtained a valid `std::wstring` from your file, you should be able to use it with SFML without problems.

Comment: Is this in visual studio because the c++ int CodeBlocks doesnt have a codecvt library
is it only in visual c++
@nvoigt

Comment: It's not Visual Studio, it's C++ 11. Code Blocks might not support the new features by default. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) to make it work.